how to update the SKU values
Magento Verrion: 2.4.3-p1
Problem: I tried to update the products weight value in the admin panel. I changed the weight value 1.2kgs(current) => 2.8kgs(preffereable) and press the save&exit button. but in my case nothing has been updated. after changes it's show the same value 1.2kg.

I want to know the solution for this cause, I didn't identifying this.
Is there any other way to update the values, like directly in the DB is possible?

Magento should allow you to save your update. If you start playing with the database, it will resolve your issue in the short term (that is if you know where to change) but it will bite you as well soon after.

I assume you are ok with discarding the change in the database
The alternative is to resolve the origin of the problem

To diagnose the issue, I suggest to open your browser console and the network panel particularly and verify that no error are visible from it.


thanks sir, it's solved. I couldn't able to mark as answer this.
